# Close a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window" prompt

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

How can I handle a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window prompt?"

Actually ie Window close while click on OK button, but i'm getting this prompt message
[image]

[image]

kindly help me to how to solve this. i don't want this prompt message while click on OK button.

```
ie.navigate Mod_Url

ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button").Item(1).Click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are browsing should be an `http` website instead of `https`.

If you are sure that this website is safe, you can try to modify the security settings:

IE tools -> Internet options -> Security -> Trusted sites -> Sites -> Uncheck option `Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone`

Adding `http://xx.xxx.com(the website url you accessed)` to trust site list.